# Cancel a PHImageRequest launched via an Operation

Tags: ios, swift

I have an OperationQueue where I launch multiple PHImageRequest in order to load images (via an Operation). But I want to cancel the request if I don't need the image anymore (images are in a collectionView). Initially I wanted to watch the isCancelled variable but it's not possible as I cannot override it...
I tried to put a loop after the request that loop while the request is not finished and check if isCancelled is true, if it is, it cancel the image request (I got rid of this solution, it was causing too many bugs, images were not loading..).

I come up with a solution, but there is only a short time where isCancelled can cancel the image request.

If anyone has a proper way to cancel the request, I'm here Thanks!

First idea (loop):

```
override func start() {
        if isCancelled { return }
        var imageRequested = true

        requestId = HomeViewController.imageManager.requestImage(
            for: mAsset.phasset,
            targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200),
            contentMode: .default,
            options: UIConstants.fastAssetRequestOptions,
            resultHandler: { [weak self] (result, _) -> Void in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                guard let result = result else { return }
                self.image = result

                imageRequested = false              

                if let loadingCompleteHandler = self.imageLoadingCompleteHandler {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        loadingCompleteHandler(result)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        while imageRequested {
            if isCancelled && requestId != nil {
                manager.cancelImageRequest(requestId!)
                requestId = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

Second idea (current solution):

```
override func start() {
        if isCancelled { return }        
        requestId = HomeViewController.imageManager.requestImage(
            for: mAsset.phasset,
            targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200),
            contentMode: .default,
            options: UIConstants.fastAssetRequestOptions,
            resultHandler: { [weak self] (result, _) -> Void in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                guard let result = result else { return }
                self.image = result

                if let loadingCompleteHandler = self.imageLoadingCompleteHandler {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        loadingCompleteHandler(result)
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        if(isCancelled && (requestId != nil)) {
            HomeViewController.imageManager.cancelImageRequest(requestId!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show more of your Operation code? Requesting an image from the image manager is an asynchronous task, so it is not susceptible of being simply wrapped up in an Operation without certain elaborate precautions.

Comment: This is 90% of the code, the 10% is just the constructor to set the asset to be fetched and a setter for the imageLoadingCompleteHandler. I just don't understand why I need to take precautions, like, when the Operation start, it launch either the main or start function. So adding the Operation to the OperationQueue just put the Operation in the queue and lauch it concurrently? There is something more to take into account if the operation does asynchronous stuff ?

Comment: Well, maybe it's not asynchronous. What's `UIConstants.fastAssetRequestOptions`? Please resolve all unknowns when you show code, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, here it is:
`let options  = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = false
        options.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
        options.resizeMode = .fast
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        return options`
So it is asynchronous.

Comment: It sounds to me like maybe you just need another public function that someone can call to cancel the request. — By the way, you are aware that you have overridden the wrong method? You should be overriding `main`, not `start`. If you override `start` its job is to call `main`.

Comment: Okay, so you are not synchronous; you are asynchronous. And you are networking. So what happens, `start` is called and ends _immediately_. The operation is torn down and ejected from the queue. Some time afterward, perhaps a long time afterward, the image arrives and the completion handler is performed, maybe (though I don't quite see how), but the operation is long gone. To see if I'm right, `print` in your Operation's `deinit` and `print` after your `self.image = result` and I think you'll find the former precedes the latter by some appreciable time.

Comment: Or if not, observe your Operation's `isFinished` and see if that precedes your `self.image = result`. I bet it does. The Operation finishes _instantly_.

Comment: Well, after printing in deinit and in my handler, I found that the handler is executed _before_ the deinitialization, so it appears that the operation is destroyed after the handle is executed. So I tried with `isFinished`, it is false when it execute `self.image = result` but true _inside_ my handler. Therefore, I think It is safe to add a public method to cancel the request as you mentioned because the operation is only mark as finished in my handler (I absolutely wanted to do that with `cancel()` and not even thought about adding a method..). Will try that, thanks! :)

Comment: Well, I'm a little fuzzy on the timing and I didn't try it myself, but there is this `requestId` for each Operation; if that were an instance property of the operation, you'd have a way of using it to tell the image manager to cancel that request, I believe.

Comment: However, I'm a little nervous about how you're going to do that, because you can't just go looking at the operations in the operation queue, that's a potential race condition.

Comment: Well I have in my `UICollectionViewController` a map `var loadingOperations: [IndexPath: ImageLoadOperation] = [:]` so I use the indexPath of the cell to get the Operation and when `didEndDisplaying` is called, I called `cancelImageFetching()` and `cancel()` on the operation. Seems to work fine!

Comment: Cool, you should write up your solution and give it as an answer, might be useful to others.

Comment: Added! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, following [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) comments, I added a public method in the Operation that call cancelImageRequest(requestId). Seems to work fine! (be sure to call cancel method too when you call cancelImageRequest, otherwise there is some Task error!)

```
func cancelImageRequest() {
    if let requestId = requestId {
        HomeViewController.imageManager.cancelImageRequest(requestId)
    }
}
```